# Ruby: add sub array of an hash together

Tags: ruby

I have

```
array_comb = {
  array1: [
    {url: 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFR8mp0gz-h93DGGhsdLmrg', name: 'MAGIC SHOP FRENCH DROP'},
    {url: 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChKgsPL1MX5z_M33fYtOPKg', name: 'Ellusionist'}],
  array2: [
    {url: 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfrhuhTDSpVhK7omh_ZIKaw', name: "Murphy's Magic"},
    {url: 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEybzfsG2WI4Hnx5hpd2uRA', name: 'TheBlueCrownMagic'}],
  array3: [
    {url: 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwlXbq5KtkdGC87oABDsfTQ', name: 'Dan & Dave'},
    {url: 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCl1WwbVpKUdQerivZpUxZLA', name: 'Theory 11'},]}
```

How can I combine the 3 sub-array into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array_comb.values.flatten
```

`values` returns an arrays of all values in the hash. This ends up being an array of arrays. `flatten` merges all the arrays into a single array.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
array_comb.flat_map(&:last)
  #=> [{:url=>"https:..."MAGIC SHOP FRENCH DROP"},
  #    {:url=>"https:..."Ellusionist"},
  #    {:url=>"https:..."Murphy's Magic"},
  #    {:url=>"https:..."TheBlueCrownMagic"},
  #    {:url=>"https:..."Dan & Dave"},
  #    {:url=>"https:..."Theory 11"}]
```